# How can I insert individual images for individual categories, while excluding some?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to edit my current wordpress theme... im editing the file template for my category pages. I have so far an idea of what to do... but I want to add a few more specific images to match its category while excluding the others... How can I add more to the statement?

I want to add 1 for Technology, 1 for Entertainment, 1 for Lifestyle, and 1 for Business.

```php
<?php if (is_category('Technology')) : ?>

<div class="container gridlove-ad-below-header round_corners">
    <div class="gridlove-ad">
    <style>
        .top_home_page { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
        @media(min-width: 500px) { .top_home_page { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
        @media(min-width: 800px) { .top_home_page { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
        .round_corners { border-radius: 5px !important;}
    </style>

    <img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://da-pulsecom.stage.site/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Store-Content-Technology.png"/>
    </div>
</div>

<?php elseif (is_category('News', 'Science')) : ?>
<h5>No store image goes here</h5>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Where you want to add images?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking; _very_ unclear what the screenshot you have shown is supposed to have to do with the code you have shown. You need to give us a _proper_ explanation of what you are even talking about here.

Comment: The image is the 'Store Content' area... its just there as a placeholder. Basically I want that area to change depending on the category.

Comment: _“but I want to add a few more specific images to match its category while excluding the others...”_ - specific how? Selected _from_ where, based on _what_? Excluding what exactly?

Comment: What “store” - are we talking WooCommerce, some other established WP shop solution, something you created on your own …?

Comment: <img class="round_corners hover-shadow" src="https://da-pulsecom.stage.site/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Store-Content-Technology.png"/> this I want it to change depending on the category. I'd place the appropriate image URL

Comment: Yes, woocommerce... it would be a simple link redirect to the woocommerce category shop

Comment: So what is the actual _problem_ then? You have shown us an `if` block that checks whether you are in a particular category, and inside that is some static HTML to show a particular image. So change the URL in the `src` there then, if you want a different image …?